# Pass a function as parameter to an external dll C#

Tags: c#, dll, parameters, dllimport

I'm trying to use an dll on my project which have a method that receives a function as parameter, but I don't know how to do that call using C#.

Here is the example that the dll manual provides.

```
do_pkd(void(*put-byte) (char));
```

I think it's an example writed in C and I don't know how to perform the same call on C#

Here is the way that I'm trying to do now

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Console.WriteLine(do_pkd(put_byte));
}

[DllImport(@"C:\pkwin32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static unsafe extern char do_pkd(Action<char> put_byte);

private static void put_byte(char s)
{
   //TO-DO
   Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

I'm receiving the following error:

> Can not perform marshalling of 'parameter # 1': Can not perform marshalling of generic types.

Comment: Is this a callback method?

Comment: I don't know, how can I know that?

Comment: `void(*put-byte) (char)` does not compile, what's that minus sign doing? Can you show the real code. It does look like `do_pkd` accepts a function pointer (aka callback) but since the code is somewhat fake, I'd be reluctant to get into detail.

Comment: The only time I've ever seen a c language call a c# function is when the c# is processing an event which is why I asked if it was a callback.  When it is a callback the c# method name is passed to the c language application as a parameter to a c language method.

Comment: How can I pass a callback function to an external dll? maybe It works

Comment: I read the manual again and found the following text "do_pkd receives a function put_byte as parameter at the moment of the decompression each uncompressed byte will be passed to user by put_file,
being at the discretion of the user the destination of the data
decompressed"

Comment: just for knowledge, this dll compress and uncompress files

Comment: There are plenty of examples of passing callback functions to pinvoke methods. Try some websearch.

Comment: Thanks, after some websearch I finally solved my problem using callback function.

Comment: @juliocesar So can you please share your research as an answer for us?